# Finding Number of ways

Tags: combinations, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

Given M digits which are between 1 to 9, Find the number of ways to form N digit number, by repeating one or more given digits such that each of M digits are present in N digit number at least once. Example if M = 3 and N = 4 Answer is 36.

Explanation - let the three digits be 1 2 3 our N = 4, digit number can be 1123, 3211, 1132, ..... repeating 1 similarly repeating 2 and three we will get the total ans.

Since answer is large find the ans % 10000000007. 1 ≤ M ≤ N ≤ 100.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't specified which programming language to use, I will use whatever language I prefer (i.e. Java). If you prefer another programming language, you can taje my code as pseudo-code (I have added sufficiently many comments in the code to explain what's going on) and translate to another programming language by yourself.

#### Clarification

Before I actually get into tackling the problem, I would like to point out that the input arguments should be a *set of digits S*, and an *integer N* that is at least the size of *S*. The way you phrase the problem appears to suggest the input arguments are *M* and *N*. This is misleading because if you consider `S = {1, 1, 3}` and `N = 4`, then it is obvious that the number of combinations in this case is less than that of your example.

#### High Level Idea

The core technique to tackle this problem is (not so surprisingly) *dynamic programming*, the sub-problems `P(L, T)` are indexed by two parameters: (1) the length `L` of the number to be constructed; and (2) the set of digits `T` that must appear in constructing the L-digit number. In your example, the parameters are: (1) `L = 4`; and (2) `T = {1, 2, 3}`.

Suppose now we want to solve the problem `P(L, S)`. Let's pick an arbitrary digit `a` from the digit alphabet (i.e. all the digits between 1 and 9 that appears in the input argument `S`).

- If `a` is in `S`, then the number of L-digit numbers that *starts with* `a` is given by `P(L - 1, S \ {a})`.
- On the other hand, if `a` is **not** in `S`, then the number of L-digit numbers that *starts with* `a` is given by `P(L - 1, S)`.

Therefore we have the following formula:

[image]

Here *Γ* denotes the digit alphabet, and `S \ {a} = S` if `a` is not in `S`.

And the base cases for this problem are `P(0, Ø) = 1` (`Ø` denotes the empty set), and `P(L, S) = 0` if `L < |S|`.

#### Code

*Update:* I have rolled back my code to mod the count by `10000000007` (the module you used in your question) instead of `1000000007` (1 zero less).

The code written in Java is given below:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;


public class Combination {
    
    /* Input arguments */
    private static int[] inputNums = {1, 2, 3};
    private static final int N = 4;
    
    // This contains all the valid digits for constructing our N-digit number 
    private static Set<Integer> validDigits;
    
    // Lookup table for sub-problems to save computation time
    private static Map<String, Long> subProbLookup;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                    
        validDigits = new HashSet<Integer>();
        List<Integer> initNums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        subProbLookup = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        
        // Initiation
        for (int i = 0; i < inputNums.length; i++) {
            validDigits.add(inputNums[i]);
            initNums.add(inputNums[i]);
        }
        
        // For ensuring the keys for the lookup table are consists
        Collections.sort(initNums);
        
        System.out.println("The number of combinations is " + countDP(N, initNums));
        
    }
    
    private static long countDP(int length, List<Integer> requiredNums) {
        
        // This corresponds to the case that not all given digits are used
        if (requiredNums.size() > length) {
            return 0;
        }
                    
        // Base Case
        if (requiredNums.size() == 0 && length == 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        
        // Check for cached result
        final String key = requiredNums.toString() + ";" + length;
        
        if (subProbLookup.containsKey(key)) {
            return subProbLookup.get(key);
        }
        
        long count = 0;
        
        for (Integer i : validDigits) {
            // Generate next sub-problem
            List<Integer> updatedNums = new ArrayList<Integer>(requiredNums);
            if (requiredNums.contains(i)) {
                updatedNums.remove(i);
            }
            count = (count + countDP(length - 1, updatedNums)) % 10000000007L;
        }

        // Cache the result
        subProbLookup.put(key, count);
        return count;
    }

}
```